# Why does jQuery .text() not return the value inside the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am missing something trivial here, but I don't get it. Why doesn't it alert `Test Value`?

```js
$('.comment-upvote-wrapper').on('click', function() {
    // Get the comments pk
    var comment_pk = $(this).closest('#comment-pk').text()
    alert(comment_pk)
})
```

```css
.comment-upvote-wrapper {
  width: max-content;
  background-color: yellow;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div hidden id="comment-pk">Test Value</div>
<div class="comment-box">
  <div class="comment-options">
    <div class="comment-upvote-wrapper comment-options-box">Return "Text Value"
```

Comment: Why not just using the id? var comment_pk = $('#comment-pk').text()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because `#comment-pk` is not an ancestor element of `.comment-upvote-wrapper`, it's a sibling of `.comment-box`. Therefore you need to use `closest()` to get the `.common-box`, then `prev()`:

```js
$('.comment-upvote-wrapper').on('click', function() {
  var comment_pk = $(this).closest('.comment-box').prev('#comment-pk').text();
  console.log(comment_pk)
})
```

```css
.comment-upvote-wrapper {
  width: max-content;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div hidden id="comment-pk">Test Value</div>
<div class="comment-box">
  <div class="comment-options">
    <div class="comment-upvote-wrapper comment-options-box">Return "Text Value"</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***However*** the fact that the element has an `id` attribute means there should only ever be one of them in the DOM. As such using DOM traversal to find it is redundant; you can just select it directly by its `id`:

```js
$('.comment-upvote-wrapper').on('click', function() {
  var comment_pk = $('#comment-pk').text();
  console.log(comment_pk)
})
```